# Hat-trick rules for different match/innings

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

If a bowler takes wicket in the last ball of an over and takes other two wickets in the first two balls of the next over then it is considered as Hat-trick.

But what if a bowler takes last two wickets in one match and in the next match he takes a wicket in the first ball of his very first over. Will it considered as a Hat-trick?

Similar (and related) question: What if a bowler takes last two wickets in first innings of a test match and in the second innings (of the same test match) he takes a wicket in the first ball of his very first over. Will it considered as a Hat-trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia's definition of Hat-Trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms#Hat-trick)

> a bowler taking a wicket off each of three consecutive deliveries that he bowls in **a single match** (whether in the same over or split up in two consecutive overs, or two overs in two different spells, or even spread across two innings of **a test match** or first-class cricket game).

So from the definition we can say that a Hat-Trick must be occur within **a single match**. It **can not** be spread across **two matches**. But it **can**, of course, be spread across the two innings of a double-innings match, such as a **Test match**.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Cricket)

> A hat-trick occurs in cricket when a bowler dismisses three batsmen
>   with consecutive deliveries. The deliveries may be interrupted by an
>   over bowled by another bowler from the other end of the pitch or the
>   other team's innings, but must be three consecutive deliveries by the
>   individual bowler. Only wickets attributed to the bowler count towards
>   a hat-trick; run outs do not count.

Here one thing we have to remind is that, there is no official definition or law for **Hat-Tricks**. There are no official wordings or like that as how a Hat-Trick is achieved. It is more commonly a term used by media and others who see this an individual achievement by a player. So basically it is to be left with each person's perspective as to which one is a Hat-Trick or which one is not.

Like [asked in this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/rules-for-hat-trick-while-bowling) one can argue over a Hat-Trick with a wide ball(or no-ball) in between.

Anyway in the same link I provided, there are some peculiar Hat-Tricks explained, like the one you asked.

> Some hat-tricks are particularly extraordinary. On 2 December 1988,
>   Merv Hughes, playing for Australia, dismissing Curtly Ambrose with the
>   last ball of his penultimate over and Patrick Patterson with the first
>   ball of his next over, wrapping up the West Indies first innings. When
>   Hughes returned to bowl in the West Indies second innings, he trapped
>   Gordon Greenidge lbw with his first ball, completing a hat-trick over
>   two different innings and becoming the only player in Test cricket
>   history to achieve the three wickets of a hat-trick in three different
>   overs.

So you can say it is a Hat-Trick spread over two innings/match or you dont agree at all. As I said above it is each person's perspective.

Comment: We can say Hat-trick can be spread over two innings but what about two matches? the given example is for innings only. I have doubt about two matches.

Comment: The given example is not based on any official rule or record. It is simply put in a general perspective. You can argue that it is not a Hat-Trick.

Comment: IMO it doesn't matter if it is in the same over, innings, match or series. As long as 3 wickets come off 3 balls, it is a hat-trick. But like @RKN mentioned, there is no official rule and it is one's prerogative to interpret the rule as one deems fit.

Comment: @Orangecrush - As per [this answer](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Cricket-1632/2009/4/Clarification-Hat-Trick-bowler.htm) Hat-trick must be completed within a given match.

Comment: @Sancho - I already told that the given definition is unclear not wrong. [See my answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2322/540).

Answer (score 2):

Its a hat trick for the match not matches. What next someone on 99 not out will get a single next game and claim a 100? Similarly, a hat trick doesn't count for multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

If a bowler takes last two wickets in one match and in the next match he takes a wicket in the first ball of his very first over, it will not be considered as a Hat-trick.

From [cricket.com.au](http://www.cricket.com.au/) article "[Three in three balls - but no hat-trick](http://www.cricket.com.au/news/joel-paris-three-wickets-in-three-balls-hat-trick-western-australia-south-australia-sheffield-shield/2016-03-06)":

> Western Australia quick Joel Paris has pulled off a hat-trick ***that wasn't***, taking three wickets in three consecutive balls across two matches.
>
> The left-armer, continued his bright recent form by taking a wicket with his first ball in WA's Sheffield Shield match against South Australia at the WACA Ground on Sunday, which was also the first delivery of the Redbacks innings.
>
> Seven days earlier, Paris had steered the Warriors to a thrilling win over Queensland with 4-78 on the final day of their Shield clash in Perth, including two wickets from the final two balls of the match to secure the 24-run win.
>
> The wicket of Weatherald on Sunday made it three wickets in three balls for Paris, spread over a week, ***but it isn't recorded as a hat-trick as the feat was achieved over two matches***.

From [Western Australia's tweet](https://twitter.com/WACA_Cricket/status/706326982590476288):

> we realise Paris' 1st ball wicket doesn't constitute a hat-trick as ***you can't have a HT across 2 games!*** Just a bit of fun!