# Can a hat-trick be separated by a maiden over?

Tags: cricket, terminology

In the game of cricket, if one bowler gets two wickets with the last two balls of one over, then in their next over bowl a maiden, and then in their third over take a wicket with the very first ball, does this count as a hat-trick?

Answer (score 9):

No, a hat trick is a wicket with each of three consecutive balls by the bowler<sup>1</sup>. They can be split across overs, or even across innings in a two innings match, but it has to be three consecutive balls.

For avoidance of doubt, there is no definition within the [Laws of Cricket](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/) (or even any playing conditions in common use that I'm aware of) for exactly what a "hat trick" consists of (see various [other](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/rules-for-hat-trick-while-bowling) [questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/hat-trick-rules-for-different-match-innings) on this site for examples) - but I don't think you'd find much support anywhere for trying to claim a hat trick of this form.

[1] From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Cricket): "A hat-trick occurs in cricket when a bowler dismisses three batsmen with consecutive deliveries."

Comment: Hatricks can even be spread across matches I think. (Merv Hughes had one such, if I'm not wrong)

Comment: @Yaitzme: [citation needed] for that assertion. I'd put a small amount of money on the fact that the Merv Hughes incident you're thinking of is that mentioned in [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/hat-trick-rules-for-different-match-innings) where he took a hat-trick across three overs.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - You are right on the Merv Hughes incident. :) Also, the term 'hattrick' is just a media-introduced term and not an official term persay. So, there are going to be differences in the way people interpret a hattrick.

Comment: From what I've read so far, people DO NOT consider (for some strange reason) wickets spread over matches as hattricks. So I take back my assertion, although I believe, it makes no sense to impose rules with little logic on hattricks.